# Can I be forgiven forse all of the things that I've done?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, forgiveness

I know that this isn't the theme of the discussion But I wanted to confess  what I've done and I wanted to know if I can be forgiven.
I watched porn ,hentai and I masturbated watching them 3 times without knowing that they were haram.
I discovered that they are haram acts like one month ago and I regret all of the things that I done.
I will NEVER do them again from now on But I don't know if I'll be forgiven.
I feel really bad for really thinking that they weren't haram.
I feel so stupid But here in Italy and in the West it seemed pretty normal.
Could I ever be forgiven?
(Sorry for eventual errors)

Comment: Islam SE is not a peer support group. Therefore this question is off-topic.

Comment: [39:53](https://quran.com/39/53)

Comment: @Italian Girl - Allah (ﷻ) forgives those who sincerely repent, whether their sins are major or minor, few or many. So yes, you could be forgiven :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell whether this is a sincere question or you just a troll. But as Islam preachers always give benefit of the doubt as we don't know what is inside another person's heart.

So sister, the issue of pornography is not limited to Italy or the western world. Unfortunately with advancement of technology and the ever increasing presence of smartphones it is a world wide epidemic.

One to thing to note is that in Islam, all sins can be forigiven by Allah except Shirk. Even for shirk, Allah is His All-Encompassing Mercy has said if one repents sincerely (before death or it's signs appear) , the person starts with a clean slate.

> And those who do not invoke with Allah another deity or kill the soul
>   which Allah has forbidden [to be killed], except by right, and do not
>   commit unlawful sexual intercourse. And whoever should do that will
>   meet a penalty.
>
> Multiplied for him is the punishment on the Day of Resurrection, and
>   he will abide therein humiliated
>
> Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them
>   Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah
>   Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> And he who repents and does righteousness does indeed turn to Allah
>   with [accepted] repentance.
>
> Quran ([25:68-71](https://quran.com/25/68-77?translations=20))

Also in another place w.r.t shirk of Christians, Allah says:

> They have certainly disbelieved who say, " Allah is the third of
>   three." And there is no god except one God. And if they do not desist
>   from what they are saying, there will surely afflict the disbelievers
>   among them a painful punishment.
>
> So will they not repent to Allah and seek His forgiveness? And Allah
>   is Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> Quran ([5:73-74](https://quran.com/5/73-83?translations=20))

Coming to your "confession". If you are a muslim, please understand that unlike the Catholic church there is no real concept of confessing one's sin before another individual.

> Narrated Abu Huraira: "I heard Allah's Apostle saying. "All the sins
>   of my followers will be forgiven except those of the Mujahirin (those
>   who commit a sin openly or disclose their sins to the people). An
>   example of such disclosure is that a person commits a sin at night and
>   though Allah screens it from the public, then he comes in the morning,
>   and says, 'O so-and-so, I did such-and-such (evil) deed yesterday,'
>   though he spent his night screened by his Lord (none knowing about his
>   sin) and in the morning he removes Allah's screen from himself."
>   (Translation of Sahih Bukhari, Good Manners and Form (Al-Adab), Volume
>   8, [Book 73, Number 95](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/78/99))"

**To receive forgiveness from God there are three requirements:**

1. Recognizing the offense itself and its admission before God.
2. Making a commitment not to repeat the offense.
3. Asking God for forgiveness.

***If the offense was committed against another human being(s), a fourth condition is added:***

1. Recognizing the offense before those against whom offense was committed and before God.

2.Committing oneself not to repeat the offense.

3.Doing whatever needs to be done to rectify the offense (within reason) and asking pardon of the offended party.

4. Asking God for forgiveness.

Apologies if my answer might have offended you in any way or form. I have no such intent. But I wish you the best and inshallah your faith will stronger as you learn more about Islam from the Quran and Sahih Hadiths.

Salaam!

Answer (score 1):

> Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Prophet
>   of Allah said: "There was a man from among a nation before you who
>   killed ninety-nine people and then made an inquiry about the most
>   learned person on the earth. He was directed to a monk. He came to him
>   and told him that he had killed ninety-nine people and asked him if
>   there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted. He replied in
>   the negative and the man killed him also completing one hundred. He
>   then asked about the most learned man in the earth. He was directed to
>   a scholar. He told him that he had killed one hundred people and asked
>   him if there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted. He
>   replied in the affirmative and asked, 'Who stands between you and
>   repentance? Go to such and such land; there (you will find) people
>   devoted to prayer and worship of Allah, join them in worship, and do
>   not come back to your land because it is an evil place.' So he went
>   away and hardly had he covered half the distance when death overtook
>   him; and there was a dispute between the angels of mercy and the
>   angels of torment. The angels of mercy pleaded, 'This man has come
>   with a repenting heart to Allah,' and the angels of punishment argued,
>   'He never did a virtuous deed in his life.' Then there appeared
>   another angel in the form of a human being and the contending angels
>   agreed to make him arbiter between them. He said, 'Measure the
>   distance between the two lands. He will be considered belonging to the
>   land to which he is nearer.' They measured and found him closer to the
>   land (land of piety) where he intended to go, and so the angels of
>   mercy collected his soul".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> In another version: "He was found to be nearer to the locality of the
>   pious by a cubit and was thus included among them". Another version
>   says: **"Allah commanded (the land which he wanted to leave) to move
>   away and commanded the other land (his destination) to draw nearer and
>   then He said: "Now measure the distance between them.' It was found
>   that he was nearer to his goal by a hand's span and was thus
>   forgiven".** It is also narrated that he drew closer by a slight
>   movement on his chest.
>
> Riyad as-Salihin, The Book of Miscellany Arabic/English book
>   reference  : Book 1, Hadith 20

It is not apparent, perhaps, but the deep gist here is that as long as one is sincere with his/her repentance, even killing all those people can be forgiven—to the point that Allah is willing to break the laws of physics to that end.